# Runnable jar file error

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

When I open a .jar file through CMD by using the following command:

```
java -jar myapp.jar"
```

I get the following error: "Main Class Not Found. Program Will Exit.."
Myapp.jar has a manifest file which looks like the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: EMP_details.login
```

I made this .jar file by going to Project>export>Jar, in Eclipse.

How can I avoid/fix this error?

Comment: you need to manually add the main class in the manifest file

Comment: i iz fed upz wit yu talkin lik dis

Comment: @Luigi Mendonza         I add that way also in bin folder of class files but still it give error of not found main class program will exit.what to do?

Comment: @james Diduzun so what can I say?

Comment: @JamesDidzun plz sir help me sorting ou the problem...

Comment: Project > Export > Java > Runnable JAR file... Then select the Lunch Configuration and Export destination. Works fine for me.

Comment: @paul vegas Did you add manifest file manualy or it genrated automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Try to made jar by eclipse>Project>export> **Runnable** Jar..
But first you have to select file with main and right click>Run As>Run Configurations.
And then you can select this file in Runnable JAR File Specificatoin Dialog > Launch configuration checkbox.

Comment: @jon skeet sir plz tell me this jar file can run on any windows or if no java runtime environment is there then it will run Thanx

Comment: @Salman Being human - Programs made in Java need to be ran on a computer containing Java, in order to execute.

Comment: If you defined a Java Version in your project, the host should have the same versior or greater.

Comment: @jon skeet  ok and what about OS??

Comment: Java currently supports Windows, Solaris, Linux, and Mac OS X.

Comment: If your project don't use third party libraries with native resources or restricted libraries like `com.sun` then you don't have problems.

Comment: @paul Vargas sir but my project need sql server database then and yes I add external jar itext and user library sqlserver jdbc driver...and sir now when I go to cmd and run "java -jar myapp.jar" the it will say unable to access..

Comment: @Paul vargasand how to know jre is installed in the pc or not?

Comment: Seems that SQL Server JDBC Driver is fully Java. I think that you don't have problem.

Comment: @paul Vargis Sir and if any pc has no java then my I get jdk with me if not the install it ..?thnx

Comment: You can to know the version with `java -version` in terminal, command line... And if the host don't have Java, you need install it

Comment: @PaulVargas sir error comes in cmd  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: EMP_details/l
ogin_1 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Sourc

Comment: @ JamesDidzun error comes in cmd  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: EMP_details/l
ogin_1 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Sourc

Comment: The Java version should be the same or more greater in the computer that the version which you use to compile the project